# Firebase dynamic links with Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm currently trying to use Firebase dynamic links (deep links). Core of the application should share the link on social media.

I've successfully created [Short Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) (200 OK) shared the link to both G+ and Facebook. But there is a problem

- Mobile browser -> deep link -> successful redirect
- G+ app -> deep link -> successful redirect
- Facebook app -> deep link (not installed my app) -> install -> continue -> success
- **Facebook app -> deep link (installed my app) -> opens Playstore app with my app displayed instead of running the app**

I'm using http scheme as suggested on Android developers site:

```
    <activity android:name=".LinkActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="..."/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So How can I properly use Firebase dynamic link with Facebook app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook uses [App Links](http://applinks.org) tags for launching other apps (and only on Android — it's been broken on iOS for almost a year). Firebase does not automatically host App Links tags for Dynamic Links, so this is the expected default behavior on Android.

There is no way to manually specify these tags in Firebase, so you'll need to host them yourself on your fallback URL, which Firebase will then scrape and pass through. Alternatively, you can take a look at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team), which hosts App Link tags be default.

Comment: "you'll need to host them yourself on your fallback URL, which Firebase will then scrape and pass through."
I know it is not in your interest to explain how the competition works but can you please elaborate on how this scraping process will work?